# Regular expression to format mobile number

Tags: php, regex, php-7

I have the following `PHP` to format the MobileNumber

```
<?php

function formatMobileNumberWithDialingCode($mobileNo, $defaultDialingCode = '')
{
    $validDialingCodes = [
        357,
        385,
        371
    ];

    if (preg_match('/^(\+|00)/', $mobileNo)) {
        $tempMobileNo = preg_replace('/^(\+|00)(.*?)/', "$2", $mobileNo);
        foreach ($validDialingCodes as $dialingCode) {
            if (preg_match('/^' . $dialingCode . '/', $tempMobileNo, $matches)) {
                $tempMobileNo = preg_replace('/^(' . $dialingCode . '(0+)?)(.*?)/', $dialingCode . "$2", $tempMobileNo);
                break;
            }
        }
        return $tempMobileNo;
    }

    // Add 0 or 00 if it starts from 0{dialing} or {dialing}
    $convertedMobileNo = '00' . $defaultDialingCode . $mobileNo;
    foreach ($validDialingCodes as $dialingCode) {
        if (preg_match('/^' . $dialingCode . '/', $mobileNo)) {
            $convertedMobileNo = preg_replace('/^(' . $dialingCode . ')(0+)?(.*?)/', '00' . $dialingCode . "$3", $mobileNo);
            break;
        }
    }
    return preg_replace('/^(\+|00)(.*?)/', "$2", $convertedMobileNo);
}

$mobileNoSamples = [
    '385' => [
        '441234568',
        '+371441234568',
        '+3850441234568',
        '00385441234568'
    ],
    '371' => [
        '551234567',
        '+385551234567',
        '+3710551234567',
        '00371551234567'
    ]
];    foreach ($mobileNoSamples as $dialingCode => $mobileNos) {
        foreach ($mobileNos as $mobileNo) {
            echo '(' . $dialingCode . ') ' . $mobileNo . ' -> ' . formatMobileNumberWithDialingCode($mobileNo, $dialingCode) . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
```

Which outputs as

```
(385) 441234568 -> 385441234568 [CORRECT]
(385) +371441234568 -> 371441234568 [CORRECT]
(385) +385441234568 -> 385441234568 [CORRECT]
(385) +3850441234568 -> 3850441234568 [WRONG] (CORRECT - 385441234568)
(385) 00385441234568 -> 385441234568 [CORRECT]
(371) 551234567 -> 371551234567 [CORRECT]
(371) +385551234567 -> 385551234567 [CORRECT]
(371) +371551234567 -> 371551234567 [CORRECT]
(371) +3710551234567 -> 3710551234567 [WRONG] (CORRECT - 371551234567)
(371) 00371551234567 -> 371551234567 [CORRECT]
```

As you can see that it's not formatting properly for the number which has 0 immediately after dialing code (which should be removed).
Can anyone help me to modify the function to fix the `[WRONG]` cases?

**Correct Format** - `[InternationalDialingCode Without leading + or 00] [Mobile Number without leading Zero]`

Thanks

Comment: For which country do you need mobile phone validation for? Do you need the international dialling code? etc

Comment: Just FYI: `.*?` at the end of the patten does not match anything.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew doesn't `.*?` match just any one character at the end?

Comment: `*?` matches as few as possible. Since it can match 0, it will match zero.

Comment: How about `preg_replace('~^\+?0*(?:'.$dialingCode.')?0*~', $dialingCode, $mobileNo);`? See live demo https://3v4l.org/ioKUW

Comment: `$mobileNo` may or may not have $dialingCode along with it

Comment: I used your input array for demo. If you could have something else as input please provide it in your question.

Comment: Please check the updated case: (371) +385551234567 -> 385551234567 [CORRECT] Where 371 default Dialing code but mobileNo itself has 385

Comment: How about `(371) 00385441234568`?

Comment: @revo will result as 385441234568

Comment: Does `$mobileNo` have a fix length?

Comment: @revo not really

Comment: Okay please check this https://3v4l.org/7raoH

Answer (score 0):

You could limit the first digit after the `+` or `00` to be "any digit but `0`".

```
/^(\+|00)?([1-9]\d+)$/
```

Comment: This is not even close to my requirement.